# HLS stream with jwplayer using requirejs

Tags: requirejs, jwplayer, http-live-streaming

I would like to use JWPlayer loading by RequireJS to play HLS streams. But I have a problem with it.

All the single files are working for me ( for example .mp4 files ) except the streams.

I've created a [plunker example](http://goo.gl/dXAtYW), in the playlist there is an .mp4 file and a test stream from the jwplayer's site and the stream doesn't work.

Please help me, because if the JWPlayer can not work with RequireJS we will not buy the official licence :(

Comment: JWPlayer 7 works with requirejs as you can see in your example, however to play HLS stream you need Premium or Enterprise license, it does not work with free edition.

Comment: yes, it works with requirejs and of coure I had premium key, but I discovered that the problem is not linked to the stream. It is linked to the flash player and I think the flash player can not get the jwplayer from window.jwplayer. So finally I applied the patch and added manualy this line:
window.jwplayer = jwplayer
after it works :)